What is the difference between `some-struct?` and `#<some-struct>` in Racket?
I have a struct
(struct client-sock-addr (host port))

I have a toText function
(define (toText.v1 addr)
  (string->chunked-string (format "<client-sock-addr ~a ~a>" (client-sock-addr-host addr) (client-sock-addr-port addr))))

When this code is executed, I get a contract violation error:
client-sock-addr-host: contract violation
  expected: client-sock-addr?
  given: #<client-sock-addr>
  context...:
   client-sock-addr-host

I am relatively new to Racket, and I have been reading over the docs, and I can't for the life of me figure out what #<...> means. It looks like it's what the REPL spits out when you construct an instance of the type, but then why does the function fail saying it's not of type client-sock-addr??
Thank you.

You probably have two different definitions of the structure and your function is using one of them with a value created via the other definition.

See https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html#%28part..Structure.Type_.Generativity%29

@Shawn thanks, that indeed was the problem! Do you want to make your comment an answer so I can mark it the correct one?

I've been looking for a duplicate since I'm sure it's been asked before, but the best I can find is this answer to a different question about the types of structs.

Unless it's a prefab structure, two calls to struct will create two different incompatible structure types, even if they have the same name and fields and printed representation. You can't pass a value created by the first struct's constructor to an accessor function of the second struct, which appears to be what's happening here.
A demonstration:
#lang racket/base

(module a racket/base
  (provide x y)
  (struct foo (bar))
  (struct prefab-foo (bar) #:prefab)
  (define x (foo 1))
  (define y (prefab-foo 1)))
(require 'a)

(struct foo (bar))
(struct prefab-foo (bar) #:prefab)
(foo? x) ; #f
(prefab-foo? y); # t


#<client-sock-addr> is an example of an unreadable value; the default printed representation of an opaque struct (one that's not transparent or prefab) that doesn't have a custom write method.
(In other words, it is how Racket displays an object it doesn’t know how to display to you.)
